# Modifiying an xcode strings file post Archive: Converting Binary to UTF-8

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, bash

During the build and archive of my application the `.strings` files are copied into the application bundle, e.g.

```
CopyStringsFile
/Users/Systems/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-dqtbpsfqkwnliuflrsytopqbuvpr/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Evolve/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Evolve.app/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
MyProject/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
    cd /Users/Systems/luke/repos/MyProject/MyProject
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    builtin-copyStrings --validate --inputencoding utf-8 --outputencoding binary --outdir /Users/Systems/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-dqtbpsfqkwnliuflrsytopqbuvpr/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Evolve/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Evolve.app/en.lproj
-- MyProject/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
```

Unzipping the ipa and loading the string file into a text editor shows the binary content.

I would like to use bash to read the content of the strings file in ASCII UTF-8, find and replace some strings and encode it into binary again.

Specifically, how should I decode the contents of the file into ASCI?

Comment: What about using `sed`? Maybe sounds basic answer, but do not know exactly how complex are the changes to be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out it was a super simple bash command:

```
plutil -convert xml1 <PATH_TO_STRINGS_FILE>
```

And to convert it back again:

```
plutil -convert binary1 <PATH_TO_STRINGS_FILE>
```